# How to add product attribute (size) to Bigcommerce category listing

Tags: attributes, size, categories, product, bigcommerce

I am trying to add the product attribute (in this case the sizes in stock) to the listing on the category page.[To clarify I've included these pics - I'm talking about these attributes that are displayed on the product page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6Awy.png), [and I'd like to display them here so that people can easily see what sizes are left in stock.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkRiS.png)

If anyone knows how to do this please let me know.

This is what I've tried so far: 
I have found the code that displays the product attributes on the product page:

```html
<div class="productAttributeList" style="%%GLOBAL_HideProductAttributeList%%"> %%GLOBAL_ProductAttributeList%% </div>
```

And found where I'd like it to go in Snippets/CategoryProductsItem.html. I also added the following to the top of this file as I figured the div tag above refers to something is going to need to be called for each product.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="%%GLOBAL_CdnAppPath%%/javascript/product.attributes.js?‌​%%GLOBAL_JSCacheToke‌​n%%"></script>
```

It's not working. I know I'm missing something, but not sure what... any help would be appreciated. ladygolfwear.com.au for reference.

Comment: Please add these details in question itself

Comment: @thannes I read your answer to a similar question back in 2015 where you said to edit the snippet %%GLOBAL_CategoryProductListing%%. I can't see this snippet any longer - any ideas?

Comment: Yes it is possible

Comment: @R.K.Bhardwaj can you elaborate please?

Comment: Yea I can do something calling the options_set value from details page to category page but currently, bigcommerce remove blueprint themes so it's no longer available in new trial store. it is available in old store and I have not any old store so with the help I can send you full code for example.